# How to parse dynamic json when having dynamic index with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

From the below Json, I want to get "OutletID" from index 1 object and this index will change dynamically(ex: it may have 1 or more data obejcts). Using SelectToken fron JSON.NET how can we achieve this? without any class creation.

```
{
"status": {
    "rcode": 200,
    "message": "OK"
},
"data": {
    "0": {
        "SubFranchiseID": "0",
        "OutletID": "607",
        "OutletName": "Spill "
    },
    "1": {
        "SubFranchiseID": "0",
        "OutletID": "32",
        "OutletName": "PizzaRoma"
    }
},
"hash": "b262c62ea3c8c693ad35210289a487d6963434d7"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, if you want the element with index 1:

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(@string);

var data = (JToken)json.SelectToken("data");

var results = data == null
    ? Enumerable.Empty<dynamic>()
    : (from item in data
       select item.First.ToObject<dynamic>());

var outletId = results.ToList()[1].OutletID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code...The above code is working fine... Is there any way to do it using SelectToken other than above way?

Comment: Yes....because in my project we are getting the required fields from the database. for ex: json.SelectToken("comment.comments") and comments having dynamic length...so I want to frame a query like SelectToken("comment.comments[comment.Comments.length-1].value")?
is this possible?

Comment: I don't follow, but from what I understand what you need can be done with the code above. It seems like you want the last item (`var outletId = results.ToList()[results.Count() - 1].OutletID;`).

Comment: Yes correct, but my from db value will come as dynamic property so for that I need to write a query